# Can't embed correctly Window in PyGTK with Socket

Tags: sockets, pygtk

I'm following the the tutorial on PyGTK socket where you embed a xterm window to another application.

I downloaded the file from here: http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/socket.py

When I run it following this: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq19.015.htp I get two different results:

1. On Ubuntu Karmic Koala (GTK 2.16) the xterm appears detached from the socket window and it not usable.
2. On Lucid Lynx (GTK 2.17) the xterm window disappears, and the socket window seems to get the background from the xterm, but nothing happens and of course, it's not usable.

I've modified the script to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
from subprocess import Popen

def plugged_event(widget):
    print "Inserted a widget"

window = gtk.Window()
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
window.show()

socket = gtk.Socket()
window.add(socket)
socket.connect("plug-added", plugged_event)
sock_id = str(socket.get_id())
cmd = ["xterm", "-into", sock_id]
Popen(cmd)
socket.show()

gtk.main()
```

Everything seems to work fine, the xterm is embedded to the socket window, but I can't use the keyboard on it and the cursor appears empty. This is the same in either versions of GTK. So, does any one know if this can be fixed or if this is a Bug?

Answer (score 1):

On first glance that seems like a bug in the xterm plug/socketing. I can reproduce on Lucid. If you have vim-gtk installed, replace your cmd with:

```
cmd = ["gvim", "--socketid", sock_id]
```

And your script runs fine to embed vim.

Comment: Right, it works fine. But actually the problem is with rdesktop. Maybe GTK doesn't like working with non-GTK stuff. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I can reproduce your bug without rdesktop.